# How to get Google Sheets (Google Finance) to show today's close value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance, google-finance-api

I am able to get todays high / low / open with below formula correctly.

```
=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:CIPLA", "HIGH"))  // considering changing second param
```

but I cant get the today's close with below formula.

```
=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:CIPLA", "CLOSE"))
```

it gives below error -> "Function GOOGLEFINANCE parameter 2 value is invalid for the symbol specified"

Comment: I checked the [stock](https://finance-preprod.sandbox.google.com/quote/CIPLA:NSE?window=5D) manually in Google Finance site, If you will see the 5D data, the latest date May 25 onward is not yet available. I tried getting the close date from a range of date and the last valid data was from May 24. `=GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:CIPLA", "CLOSE", today()-7,today())`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need to specify the date and I was only able to get the close from the previous day

```
=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:CIPLA", "CLOSE",TODAY()-1))
```

Comment: yes @JohnA it never give todays close it seems. It always give yesterdays close.